# Creating a batch file that runs 4 times a day and execute 14 batch files from different folders?

Tags: batch-file

How to create a batch file that runs 4 times a day and execute 14 batch files from different folders? whose logs are directed to that 14 folders itself as per the batch file format and moving logs from those 14 folders to a common place?

Answer (score 0):

To point you in the right direction:

- Use `start` to start each of the 14 batch files
- Use task scheduler (`schtasks` from cmd) to schedule it 4 times a day
- Use `>` to redirect stdout for logging
- Use `copy` to copy the logs to a common place